# passport does not seem to include a 'login' function in nest.js

Tags: nestjs, passport.js

I'm trying to implement passport in nest.js, and think I am relatively close, but I don't seem to be able to find the login function in passport. Not certain there is one in passport, and I may have misunderstood the order of things, but the three different online instructions I found all seem to eventually call a function called login, and neither of them seem to create it. So am I just not thinking straight?

Step one, the local strategy:

```
import { Strategy } from 'passport-local';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';


@Injectable()
export class LocalStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
    super();
  }
  async validate(email: string, password: string): Promise<any> {
    console.log(`LocalStrategy.validate: email=${email}, password=${password}`);
    const user = await this.authService.signin(email, password);
    if (!user) {
      console.log(`LocalStrategy.validate: user not found`);
      throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }
    console.log(`LocalStrategy.validate: user found`);
    return user;
  }
}
```

I'm calling signing instead of validateUser, but that should not make a difference, and that function exists in the authService

```
  async signin(email: string, password: string) {
    //Find the user in the database
    const [storedUser] = await this.usersService.find(email);
    if (!storedUser) {
      throw new NotFoundException(`User ${email} not found`);
    }
    console.log(`storedUser: ${JSON.stringify(storedUser)}`);

    //Hash the provided password with the salt from the database
    const [storedSalt, storedHash] = storedUser.password.split('.');
    console.log(`storedSalt: ${storedSalt}`);
    const hash: Buffer = (await scrypt(password, storedSalt, 32)) as Buffer;


    //Compare the hashed password with the hashed version from the database
    if (hash.toString('hex') !== storedHash) {
      throw new BadRequestException('Invalid password');
    } else {
      return storedUser;
    }

  }
```

It works by it self (if I just call /signing), I can also call it by calling this.localStrategy.validate, but the document seem to suggest I should use login, which is as far as I can tell an unknown function
So below does not work:

```
  @UseGuards(LocalAuthGuard)
  @Post('/signin')
  async signinUser(
    @Body() body: any,
    @Session() session: any
  ) {
    console.log(`signinUser, body: ${JSON.stringify(body)}`);
    const user = login(body.email, body.password)
      //await this.localStrategy.validate(body.email, body.password);
    //session.userId = user.id;
    return user;
  }
```

But using this.localStrategy.validate works, but not certain if I am calling passport or using passport correctly. I.E. why call it in the first place if all it does is wrap the signing function, feels like there should be something around it?

This is the whole controller

```
import {
  Controller,
  Get,
  Post,
  Patch,
  Body,
  Param,
  Session,
  UseGuards,
  UseInterceptors,
  Query,
  Delete,
  NotFoundException,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthGuard } from "@nestjs/passport";
import { PassportModule} from "@nestjs/passport";
import { UsersService } from './users.service';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { UserEntity} from "./user.entity";
import { CreateUserDto } from './dtos/create-user.dto';
import { LocalStrategy } from "./auth-strategy/local.strategy";
import { LocalAuthGuard} from "./local-auth-guard";


@Controller('users')
export class UsersController {
  constructor(
    public usersService: UsersService,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private localStrategy: LocalStrategy,
  ) {}

  @Post('/signup')
  async createUser(
    @Body() body: CreateUserDto,
    @Session() session: any
  ) {
    const user = await this.authService.signup(body);
    //session.userId = user.id;
    return user;
  }
  @UseGuards(LocalAuthGuard)
  @Post('/signin')
  async signinUser(
    @Body() body: any,
    @Session() session: any
  ) {
    console.log(`signinUser, body: ${JSON.stringify(body)}`);
    const user = login(body.email, body.password)
      //await this.localStrategy.validate(body.email, body.password);
    //session.userId = user.id;
    return user;
  }


  @Get()
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('local'))
  findAllUsers(@Query('email') email: string) {
    // logic to find all users
    console.log('findAllUsers');
    return this.usersService.find(email);

  }
  @Get('/:id')
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('local'))
  async findUser(@Param('id') id: string) {
    console.log(`What am I dooing here?`)
    const user = await this.usersService.findOne(id);
    if (!user) {
      throw new NotFoundException(`user not found: ${id}`);
    }
    return user;
  }

  @Patch(':id')
  updateUser(
    @Param('id') id: string,
    @Body() body: any
  ) {
    return this.usersService.update(id, body);
  }

  @Delete(':id')
  removeUser(@Param('id') id: string) {
    return this.usersService.remove(id);
  }
}
```

The instructions I'm trying to follow:
https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/passport

Answer (score 0):

OK, so the whole login was a red hearing, turns out I was just not thinking clearly, that is the function's own name (I feel a bit like a fool now)

The problem was simple, it's the LocalAuthGuard that calls the validate function, and it wasn't working because I had no username (in my testing I sent it as a email, and the guard just gave me a 400).

At least I learnt that much now :)